# Vue3 v-for index is always 0 when I click on child loop

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I have array and inside of it have weekdays.
example: mainList:

```js
[
  { id: '1', name: 'st1', weekdays: ['TUE', 'WED', 'MON', 'THU'] },
  { id: '2', name: 'sty5676', weekdays: ['FRI', 'MON', 'TUE', 'THU'] },
  { id: '3', name: 'st2', weekdays: ['TUE', 'THU', 'WED'] }
]
```

I want to display this data like below:
[output display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89eV0.png)

Weekdays will display but only blue color when value exists in weekdays key.

But here problem is when I click on Monday on 2nd row(from the above image), change the color to transparent. But I'm getting index 0 everytime.

How can i achieve this.

I'm new to this community and ofcourse I'm new to this Vue3 Javascript also. Please let me know if I miss any details.

HTML code:

```html
<div
  v-for="(st, index) in mainList"
  :key="strategy"
  class="flex flex-row justify-between gap-x-2"
>
  <div>{{ st.id }}</div>
  <div>{{ st.name }}</div>
  <div>
    <!-- Week days -->
    <div class="flex items-center">
      <input
        id="mon"
        v-model="st.weekdays"
        type="checkbox"
        :value="st.weekdays.includes('MON') ? 'MON' : false"
        checked="st.weekdays.includes('MON')"
        class="sr_only hidden peer"
        @click="changeWeekdays($event, st.id)"
      />
      <label
        for="mon"
        class="px-2 py-1 w-12 text-sm border text-center rounded-md cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-900 peer-checked:border-transparent duration-200 ease-in-out"
        >Mon
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="flex items-center">
      <input
        id="tue"
        v-model="st.weekdays"
        type="checkbox"
        :value="st.weekdays.includes('TUE') ? 'TUE' : false"
        checked="st.weekdays.includes('TUE')"
        class="sr_only hidden peer"
        @click="changeWeekdays($event, st.id)"
      />
      <label
        for="tue"
        class="px-2 py-1 w-12 text-sm border text-center rounded-md cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-900 peer-checked:border-transparent duration-200 ease-in-out"
        >Tue
      </label>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .

    <div class="flex items-center">
      <input
        id="fri"
        v-model="st.weekdays"
        type="checkbox"
        :value="st.weekdays.includes('FRI') ? 'FRI' : false"
        checked="st.weekdays.includes('FRI')"
        class="sr_only hidden peer"
        @click="changeWeekdays($event, st.id)"
      />
      <label
        for="fri"
        class="px-2 py-1 w-12 text-sm border text-center rounded-md cursor-pointer focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-600 peer-checked:bg-blue-900 peer-checked:border-transparent duration-200 ease-in-out"
        >Fri
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script block:

```js
methods: {
    changeRundays(e, id) { }
```

In this I'm getting first record's id everytime though I click on 2nd or 3rd row in the list.

Please let me know.

Comment: You're re-using the same id on your inputs so whenever you click any label it's always corresponding to the first iteration of inputs.  Also, your `key` should be unique per iteration.